# ASP.Net Core - Adding Scheduler Task

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, quartz-scheduler, scheduler

I am relatively new in [ASP.Net Core](http://www.asp.net/core).

I want to implement task scheduler for my [ASP.Net Core](http://www.asp.net/core) App.

What I found is this-

http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HowToRunBackgroundTasksInASPNET.aspx

But I can't find any way to implement this in my app.

Can anyone please help of giving a go through type tutorial link to implement Task Scheduler in ASP.Net.

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: I suggest look into hangfire https://github.com/HangfireIO/Hangfire/pull/604

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use a third part library like Hangfire I think a simple solution is to create a powershell script that calls any API in you application that will execute your tasks.

Here's an example PS script that will make a GET request to any url you specify.

```
$url="http://www.myapp.com/api/runjob"
$content=(New-Object System.Net.WebClient).DownloadString("$url");

$Logfile = "D:\Temp\job.log"
Add-content $Logfile -value $content
```

Then run that script in the Task Scheduler.